# Changing class name of adjacent select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having two `select` elements as following:
Sorry previously i made mistake..  because exactly i am having like  this

```
<td>
    <select class="services_list1"></select>
</td>
<td>
    <select class="services_list2"></select>
</td>
```

If I change any option on `.services_list1` I need to change the class name of second select element where as `.services_list2`. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can do this through the `change` event on your `.services_list1` element by using [**jQuery's `next()` method**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the next element:

```
$('.services_list1').change(function() {
    // Add a class to .services_list2
    $(this).next().addClass('newClass');
});
```

---

#### Demo

In this demo, if you change the first `select` option, the second `select` will be given a new class and its styling will change.

```js
$('.services_list1').change(function() {
  // Add a class to .services_list2
  $(this).next().addClass('newClass');
});
```

```css
.newClass {
    background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="services_list1">
  <option>Change Me</option>
  <option>Select This</option>
</select>
<select class="services_list2">
  <option>Value 1</option>
  <option>Value 2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$('.services_list1').change(function(){
    $(this).next().attr("class", "yourNewClassName");
});
```

In the above code, jQuery will search the next element and replace the `class` name with `yourNewClassName`.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/ `Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.` closest would get the previous, not the next.

Comment: @artm yeah, thanks for enlightening me. I have modified the answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the existing classes and add new classes to 2nd select element on selecting 1st select element then below code works.

**HTML Code**

```
<select class="services_list1">
    <option>Value1</option>
    <option>Value2</option>
    <option>Value3</option>
</select>
<select class="services_list2">
    <option>Value1</option>
    <option>Value2</option>
    <option>Value3</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".services_list1").change(function(){
            $(this).next().removeClass().addClass('testCls1');
        });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7a7nmk3a/